# Tic-tac-toe game has normal and complex mode

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

In the complex mode the program prints the grid based on the user choice. I'm supposed to make the win condition to check the board. For every 3 consecutive "x" or "o" the program would add the winner to a scoreboard. At the end of the game the program is going to count the scores on the scoreboard and the whoever scores more on the scoreboard wins. Any idea how to do that with loops?

```
import random
playername = input("please enter your name: ")


x_o_list2 = []
n = int(input("your grid size"))
for i in range(0, n):
    row = []
    for j in range(0, n):
        row.append("_")
    x_o_list2.append(row)


# creates the grid
def board():
    for i in range(len(x_o_list2)):
        for j in range(len(x_o_list2[i])):
            print(x_o_list2[i][j], end='|')
        print("\b", end='')
        print()


# print welcome message to the user
print("Hello ", playername)
Player = input("Pleas choose to play with (X or O)")
Pc = ''
if Player == 'X' or Player == 'x':
    Pc = 'O'
elif Player == 'O' or Player == 'o':
    Pc = 'X'
turn = 'X'
count = 0
correct = True
while correct:
    board()
    # counter 
    counter = 0
    for i in Pc:
        if Pc == 3:
            pc_counter = counter + 1

    for g in Player:
        if Player == 3:Player_counter = counter + 1
            for m in x_o_list2:
          

      if n == "X" and "X" == 3:
                    print( Player, "wins")
                    Player_counter = Player + 1

    row = int(input("please choose a row to play"))
    column = int(input("please choose a column to play"))
    enter code here
    if x_o_list2[row][column] == '_':
        x_o_list2[row][column] = Player
        count += 1
        if turn == Player:
            turn = Pc
        elif turn == Pc:
            turn = Player
    elif x_o_list2[row][column] != '_':
        print("spot already taken. please choose a different spot")
    while (True):
        row1 = random.randint(0, n)
        column1 = random.randint(0, n)
        if x_o_list2[row1][column1] == "_":
            x_o_list2[row1][column1] = Pc
            count += 1
        break
```

Comment: I suggest you don't hardcode the prints but rather design your `board` to generate a list or other container to describe the board (example: `[['X', ' ', 'O'], [' ', 'X', 'O'], ['X', ' ', ' ']]`. Then have a higher level function draw the "screen" that contains the board and extra information like the round number, the score, winner, etc. By having a function for each task, the code will be easier to maintain and to expand.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need really a scoreboard for this task. You just check if the game is over and it isn't a draw, the last player who moved that's the winner.

Also don't put all inside the while loop, add more functions like isDraw(), isGameOver(), isPositionTaken(), etc.

Comment: well, it's not up to me it's an assignment that requires the score board and the win condition to check for a winner every 3 squares and see who scored more wins at the end of the game then the program announce the winner . thanks tho

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).